# how to add a block view more related to a specific attribute

Tags: magento2

I am setting up a new store for painting, where I need to add 
view more from this painter.
I have added an attribute painter, where the painter is added in the admin for the painting.

I also want to add a link to product page like - "view more from this Painter" which will redirect to another page, where all the paintings of the related painter will be shown.

Comment: If that attribute is set to be used in searches, you should be able to write some code with a link to the search results and use your attribute as the wildcard that will update per product.

Comment: @StevenJ - I can add it to the searches, but have little idea how to implement that. can you elaborate that how I can achieve this.